# Accessing VPS linux hosting like RDP in Windows

Tags: linux, vps, remote-desktop, centos6

Sorry but I'm a newbie in Linux. I have a VPS hosting of CentOS 6. Can I access it like Remote Desktop on windows to see the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a hosted Linux machine chances are that id doesn't even have "the GUI" (an X11 server and some GUI environment like KDE or Gnome) installed at all but only supports command line access via ssh.

If you really need GUI instead of command line access then the "classic" option would be VNC. There is a HowTo for this for CentOS at

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server

or at

http://www.howtoforge.com/vnc-server-installation-centos-6.5

for example ...